# bootstrap-table header and body alignments are mismatching

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-table

```
<thead>

<tr>

<th rowspan="2" data-field="id">SL</th>

<th rowspan="2" data-field="name">Region</th>

<th rowspan="2" data-field="price">PG Type</th>

<th rowspan="2" data-field="Fullname">Status</th>

<th colspan="2">CPO Patients</th>

<th colspan="5">Billing and Contract</th>

</tr>

<tr>

<th data-field="Email">Met</th>

<th data-field="Id">Possible</th>

<th data-field="Name">Billable</th>

<th data-field="Surname">Last Paid</th>

<th data-field="Fullname">Contract Info.</th>

<th data-field="Email">Payment Info.</th>

<th data-field="Iame">In Person Visit</th>

</tr>

</thead>

</table>
```

With this code i am getting the body aligned mismatch and when i have few columns then it is working fine. I am using bootstrap 3 version.
With this code i am getting the body aligned mismatch and when i have few columns then it is working fine. I am using bootstrap 3 version.

Comment: I tried your code here : https://jsfiddle.net/2Lsohk1u/ and it works fine, check and tell me.

Answer (score 0):

This will align all the th in one line ,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <tdble style="border : 1px solid black"> 

    <thead>

        <tr>
            <th colspan="2"  data-field="id">PR</th>
            <th colspan="2"  data-field="id">SL</th>

            <th colspan="2" data-field="name">Region</th>

            <th colspan="2" data-field="price">PG Type</th>

            <th colspan="2" data-field="Fullname">Status</th>

            <th colspan="1">CPO Patients</th>

            <th colspan="5">Billing and Contract</th>

        </tr>

        <tr style="text-align: center">

            <th  data-field="Email">Met</th>

            <th  data-field="Id">Possible</th>

            <th  data-field="Name">Billable</th>

            <th  data-field="Surname">Last Paid</th>

            <th  data-field="Fullname">Contract Info.</th>

            <th  data-field="Email">Payment Info.</th>

            <th  data-field="Iame">In Person Visit</th>

        </tr>

    </thead>


</table>
</body>
</html>
```